# How do I properly filter/print raw csv data by using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, csv, raw-data

So I'm in this introduction to scripting class and it is moving really fast for my understanding. We're applying regular expressions and the task is to have our fellow students pretend to be a manager and ask us to come up with the regex code to apply. Below is a screenshot of the csv along with the template code to build off of. The questions I was asked was:

Question 1) I would like to know which customers use a Visa card. Of those customers; which ones spent over $5,000 in the past 6 Months. This data will be used to provide reward points.

Question 2) I want to know the number of costumers who purchaced more recently then before, for instance bought 4 items in last 3 months but 6 items in the last 6 months. I also want to know the top longest enrolled costumers and the costumers who spent the least.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2YpX.jpg

```
import csv
import re
data = []

with open('customerData.csv') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
data.append(row)
print(data[0])
print(data[1]["Name"])
print(data[2]["Spent Past 30 Days"])
```

I can manipulate the template however I see fit so ignore the inapplicalbe sections. I know it's not very productive for the learning process but this class is seriously the worst way to learn this stuff. It's like "now you've mastered this, lets move onto this!". MF no I haven't mastered it! lol. Anyway, I would appreciate anyone to at least guide me in the right direction on how to answer these.

V/r Joshua

Comment: Hi, based on the two questions, that has nothing to do with regular expressions. You need to load the data and compute it in order to have the answers. Create a data structure for you CSV and do the computation with whatever algorithm you see fit.

Comment: Shoot I uploaded the wrong imgur:

<https://imgur.com/3y5BqHL>

We're using Codio and the data is already uploaded into the program.

Comment: It is still nothing to do with Regex. The questions are asking you to aggregate data. Regex is a searching tool.

Comment: Could I aggregate the data with Python? Someone on Reddit said this would be a job for Pandas but I'm pretty sure I'm limited to figuring this out with Python.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with virtually any programming language.